# mongodump --oplog and per database restore

Tags: mongodb, backup, mongodump, mongorestore, mongodb-oplog

I need to be able to **restore** a **single database**, even a single collection from a backup. Since `mongodump --oplog` only applies to a full instance (Replica Set), I made the following procedure to filter only the entries from the db that I want to restore from the *oplog.bson* generated by the --oplog option.
Could someone tell me if this is correct or if I'm missing something?

1. First I restore only the db (the db is *test* in this example) that I need

   > `mongorestore -d test dump/test`
2. Restore into a random collection the *oplog.bson* file generated by the --oplog option

   > `mongorestore -d oplog -c oplog  dump/oplog.bson`
3. Dump from the restored *oplog.bson* collection only the documents that refer to the db that I'm restoring

   > `mongodump -d oplog -c oplog -q "{ns:/^test[.]/}" -o oplog`
4. Restore with the --oplogReplay option using the last dump with filtered operations

   > `mongorestore --oplogReplay oplog/oplog`
5. Finally I drop the temporary oplog collection.

   > `mongo --eval "db.getSisterDB('oplog').dropDatabase()"`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, that's one way to do it..  Or you can do extra `export` after dumping specific database.

```
mongoexport -d local -c oplog.rs --query="{ns:/^test[.]/}" -o oplog.dump

2017-10-10T11:51:50.780+0300    connected to: localhost
2017-10-10T11:51:51.737+0300    local.oplog.rs  0
2017-10-10T11:51:51.938+0300    local.oplog.rs  3
2017-10-10T11:51:51.938+0300    exported 3 records
```

And you have now direct `json` dump file what you can read back

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
If my method works, I think i'll stick with it, since I end up with a much smaller portion of the oplog. Taking into account that oplog.rs is usually a big collection and without indexes, so doing the export for each database would take significantly more

Comment: Actually, you can export whole oplog.rs (without --query) and use `grep` command at mongoimport to import only wanted lines.. ;-)  `egrep   '"ns":"test.*' oplog2.dump | mongoimport -d X -c x`